# XIB files becoming blank - using iPhone sdk 4

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xib

I just updated to iPhone SDK4. The problem I am facing is - I was writing an app in iPhone sdk 3.0 just open that project in xcode 3.2.3 made some changes in xib file, now when i run this project in simulator the user interface (xib) appearing blank (with black color).

Any idea why this is happening...?

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to run directly from IB (with cmd+R) this makes it only load the view you're currently editing and does something similar to what you're describing. Save, switch to xcode and run from there, see if that helps. :)